# Process a form in a Colorbox lightbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, colorbox

I've haven't got any code yet as I'm still figuring out how to do this but essentially what i want to do is load a form in a JQuery lightbox (Colorbox preferred), submit the form (meaning save the data to my database (using PHP and a mySQL DB) and display a confirmation within the same lightbox.

Another way could be that I just load the form in the lightbox and when the user submits the form, the lightbox disappears but the main page somehow refreshes upon submission with the new data??

Is this possible? Any examples?

Comment: And another way could be to research about it on google..

Comment: It's possible but I wouldn't hold your breath for doing this in an existing lightbox solution. You basically have to get heavily involved in AJAX and instead of posting a form you'd have to grab the values using javascript and send an ajax post request instead, and then update screen upon response of that.

Comment: Thanks @Joke_Sense10, but I have and cannot seem to come up with a specific answer, so hence my post here! Thanks for your input though!

Comment: I agree with @DarrenCrabb you can use jquery.form.js plugin to do ajax form submission http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I've done something similiar.

```
function showFrame(display) {
  var colorbox = $('#colorbox');
  var overlay = $('#cboxOverlay');

   if (display) {
      colorbox.fadeIn("medium"); 
   } else {
      colorbox.fadeOut("medium");
      overlay.fadeOut("medium");
   }
}
```

The above is how you can show and hide your colorbox form, in my case I actually loaded an iframe into the colorbox. Also The function above allows for you to pass a variable to show or hide the frame.

You could basically hit this function whenever you post your form, thus your frame would close after submission.

The alternative way is to have a label or `<p>Success</p>` tag be shown when the form has been successfully posted to notify the user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Gven. It would seem that this is a slight challenge but I suppose that's what its all about!!
I have actually done this using straight pop-up windows with a refresh on closure, but with pop-ups being blocked I thought a more elegant solution would be to use a Lightbox.

Comment: Sure no problem bud. Shout if you need any help :-)